# Change angular-datepicker language

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datapicker

I'm using datapicker(https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker) for a project and I don't know how to change language of months from english to spanish.

[image: ScreenShot]

I would also like to change week name to spanish.

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: since this module uses the normal JavaScript Date objects to derive it's output, the output you receive will be based on the locale of the browser that is viewing the content.

Comment: try jquery datepicker with localization : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding locale reference js file in your html.

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/i18n/angular-locale_es-ar.js"></script>
```

The detail list can be found here.

[ngLocale](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale)

Comment: The working Plunker can be found at http://plnkr.co/edit/P62XeXAdyFS4WELsAcAv?p=preview